# choosing between internal and external (internal data storage limit)

Tags: android, storage

I'm currently preparing a puzzle App. however I'm in a dilemma if I should choose internal or external storage ( or any other by suggestions ). 
the App will contain like 30 images for the puzzle ( and an option to choose own gallery images ). I'm not a very experienced coder so the combination between best and easiest option would be great.

- For Internal storage: The settings of the App and such are more secure ,but I'm scared to hit the data limit.
- For External storage: "There is no effect on the application performance so long as the external storage is mounted on the device." (developer.android) Especially the last part about mounting scares me.

thanks in advance, 
~Olijf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not set this in your Manifest:

```
 android:installLocation="auto"
```

If you declare "auto", you indicate that your application may be installed on the external storage, but you don't have a preference of install location. The system will decide where to install your application based on several factors. The user can also move your application between the two locations.

Edit:

Checking, if external or internal storage is available:

```
boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    // We can read and write the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
} else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    // We can only read the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
} else {
    // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
    //  to know is we can neither read nor write
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer and helpfull answer, but when i use this. which kind of methods do i have to use? the internal or external codes? kinda hard to explain this question, sorry.

Comment: @Olijf which methods for example?

Comment: for example if i want to store a image. where do i have to store it? in internal or external? or other maybe?

Comment: from developer.android:  String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState(); .  its external now, but what if android chooses internal because of the AUTO option. wont give me this any troublE?

Comment: your App can be stored internal, but you can still save images in the external storage. The best approach would be checking if you can write external, if this fails save it internal

Comment: allright, this fully solved my problem, thank you!. do you know what this is called or where i can find samplecodes/info about this?